# Find references for Docker plugin

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I installed [REX-Ray](https://rexray.io/) as a docker plugin and played around with it.
Now I wanted to remove the plugin by first disabling it and the removing it.

```
docker plugin disable rexray/ebs:latest
```

The output I get is:

```
Error response from daemon: plugin rexray/ebs:latest is in use
```

I did a `docker volume rm <volume used by rexray>` but I still get the message above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/rexray/rexray/issues/1176).

> Simple fix, altough not the intended use, thus this stays a bug: restart the docker service and then remove the plugin. That worked for me multiple times.